# Why does ember ui hang during long promise call

Tags: ember.js

I have a long running call that is encapsulated by a promise,

from my understanding of promises, it allows us to do asynchronous tasks that will be dealt with when they return, and until they return the function should continue.

in my example,

1. the action is entered
2. Updates a variable that changes the ui
3. executes somethingLongRSVP

it should then exit the function and update the ui, but insted it waits for the promise to resolve before updating the ui.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kepuki/5/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console.log message in the loop will hang your UI. If you replace the console log loop with a setTimeout for example, you will see that it is updating the button before resolving the promise.

Comment: i have a loop doing a lot of work, and thought using a promise would stop it from hanging, i don't want to use set time out. do you have any other suggestions

Comment: If your work is mainly javascript code, than there is not really an option to wait before the work is done, because it will hang other javascript code when executing. So either do the work server side or show some loading indicator in your app when doing the work.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to emulate a long resolving promise, you should definitely use `setTimeout`. Otherwise the time gets spent on executing the loop (inside `doSomethingLongRSVP`) and then executing the next statement (set the variable to `clicked`). If you're gonna use `setTimeout`, it will delay the moment when promise resolves causing an effect of long network request.

Comment: i dont want emulate, i have a promise doing some work in a for loop that is causing the screen to hang. i put it in the promise because i thought that it would continue execution which it isn't. do can you recommend a better way to do this